# multer I can't display my react app images

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Hello my problem is that I use multer to store them on my server and their path on mongodb, but I can't get them to display on my react application.

thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the data from React in FormData, example:

> Node

```
import multer from "multer" // const multer = require("multer")
const upload = multer()
// in your route
app.post("/any-route", upload.array("name_id", 10), () => {
    let file = null
    if (req.files && req.files.lenght > 0){
     file = req.file[0]
    }
   // and this file you can send to MongoDB
})
```

In react you need use FormData

```
const FormData = new FormData()
FormData.append("name_id", file) // this file is the file you want send
```

Comment: ok thank you I managed to do it by modifying according to my code. But my problem is still not solved I have the link of the images on the client but it does not display anything.

Comment: I recommend use multer-s3, it is with Amazon-s3, this return the link of the image, audio or anything you send it.